# Develop an iOS app to control OS X GarageBand

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, bonjour

I need to build an app that controls GarageBand on OS X.

It's an app for iPhone that would control basic functions from OS X GarageBand like play, pause, etc.
I don't know how to build this app, how can I communicate with OS X?. Some friends told me about bonjour, but I have no experience with it and I have no idea on how to use it to build this app and yes I've read the bonjour's page.

Can someone give me some direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is CoreMidi

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CACoreMIDIRef/_index.html

Garage Band speaks midi, and if your app sends midi signals either over USB or some other protocol (like Bonjour to a listening client app) you can interact with GarageBand this way.